# Problema de encoding servlet, json e jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Criei um servlet q retorna um JSON simples. Eu consegui consumir o mesmo tranquilamente, porém ao colocar o conteúdo em uma `div` ficou da seguinte forma:

```
0: �gua
1: a�ucar
2: sal
3: canela
4: �leo
```

Ao olhar o retorno da servlet pela aba network do Chrome vi que o JSON veio com o *encoding* correto, segue o retorno:

```
[{Item: "água"}, {Item: "açucar"}, {Item: "sal"}, {Item: "canela"}, {Item: "óleo"}]
```

Percebi q o problema é apenas no ajax, então como resolvo este problema?

Tentei varias soluções e nada que achei na net resolveu, coloquei meta tag (na verdade alterei, porque já tinha), coloquei `contentType` e `encoding` no ajax e nada.

Segue meu código (já tentei com UTF-8, ISO e por último o Windows):

```js
$.ajax({
   url: '',
   data: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   encoding:"Windows-1252",
   contentType: "text/plain; charset=Windows-1252"
}).done(function(retorno){
   alert(retorno);
   var k = 0;
   $.each(retorno, function(i, item){
     criarElemento("<p>", {html: i+": "+item.Item, id: 'item_'+k}, "teste");
     k++;
   });
});
```

Comment: Coisas que eu tentaria: 1. Abre o developer tools, abre a aba `Network` e grava o ajax. Vê o content-type do request se está igual você está passando. 2. vai no seu editor, com a página servet aberta e vai no "salvar como" e escolhe UTF-8. Só o encoding do meta-description as vezes não vai. Se tiver arquivos JS também salva eles como UTF. Faria também o teste sem esses encodings 1252 no `.ajax` do JSON. É sempre mais fácil estar tudo UTF.

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou utilizar o `content-type` `"text/html"` ou `"application/json"` ?
Como codificação utiliza o UTF-8 ou ISO mesmo... 
Lembrando que o `content-type` do seu arquivo que é o .html ou .php etc, que contém as `<div>` deve estar correto também, já que você comentou que o retorno do JSON está correto, pode ser isso...

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou

Comment: como está o seu html ?
e o retorno do banco, verifica se está codificado da mesma maneira..

Comment: esta exatamente como estava não mudou nada, a saída continua a mesma

Comment: não é banco é fixo, criei pra teste então nem usei o banco, criei em string manualmente

Comment: exemplo: object.put("Item", "água");

Answer (score 2):

Cara, se estiver usando servidor de aplicação tenta isto:

Referência: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Tomcat(adiciona alinha abaixo no arquivo /conf/server.xml)

```
<Connector (...) URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Glassfish 3.0(adiciona alinha abaixo no arquivo /WEB-INF/sun-web.xml) ou Glassfish 3.1(adiciona alinha abaixo no arquivo /WEB-INF/web.xml)

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
```

Tive este problema com JSF no Glassfish, nada resolvia até descobrir esta solução...

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!!! funcionou aqui, tive q fazer acrescentar: resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); na servlet q o ajax consome.